# Get Mail Sent Notification in onActivityResult "Android"

Tags: android, email, android-manifest, android-intent

I am launching a mail activity by

//Sending mail

> final int SENT_MAIL = 1;
>
> startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,
> "Send mail"),SENT_MAIL);

and in

> onActivityResult(int req, int res,Intent data)

i am trying to find the result of email sending, so as to confirm if my mail was sent or was discarded by the user.
I am recieving null for Intent data

> i.e data =null

parameter in onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent data), res is always 0.

> ie. res = 0;

Please let me know what can be done in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to contact the developers of everything that could possibly ever respond to your `Intent` (which you do not show above) and ask them if they support `startActivityForResult()` for such an `Intent`. Odds are, few do, and you will have difficult tracking down all possible Android email clients, anyway. If they do not support `startActivityForResult()`, while you can still call that method, you will not get meaningful results in `onActivityResult()`.

Hence, what you want is impractical, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but still is there any work around..?? i just wan't a callback from native app (in this case.. i assume gmail on android phone to be a native app)

Comment: @Abhinava: "but still is there any work around..??" No. The AOSP Email application does not use `setResult()` and so will not work with `startActivityForResult()`. The Gmail application is closed source. You are welcome to contribute patches to the open source Email application to add this functionality for that specific app.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that startActivityForResult cannot be used with an intent using Gmail such as this: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("message/rfc822")` because it will return RESULT_CANCELLED everytime regardless of success? I could have sworn that it worked for me earlier but now I only get RESULT_CANCELLED.

Comment: @dylanmurphy: I am saying that unless the activity is *specifically written to support `startActivityForResult()`*, then you will get `RESULT_CANCELED` for all such requests. `ACTION_SEND`, as a general rule, is not designed to support `startActivityForResult()`, as the documentation for `ACTION_SEND` does not supply instructions for the "result" as it does for other things (e.g., `ACTION_PICK`).