# Android Activity: ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, action, send

when using ACTION_SEND to send emails, is there a way to check if result was successful?

here is my code sample:

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "abc@xyz.com" });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Subject of the Mail");
    emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "This is my sample Mail");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this posting: [Get Mail Sent Notification in onActivityResult "Android"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600149/get-mail-sent-notification-in-onactivityresult-android) it sounds like the problem is that there is no guarantee that the client responsible for handling the intent is going to setActiviyResult, so there's no one way to get it. You'll have to check to see if the client that is handling the intent will send back a status.